# Define mutate variables outside of pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'd like to have a mutate function be an input so that I can try different methods. Here's an example

```
library(dplyr)

my.df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(200))

apply.method <- function(myfun=NULL) {
  ret.df <- my.df %>%
    mutate(z = myfun())
}

external_function1 <- function(){
  x+y
}

external_function2 <- function(constant){
  x*y + constant
}

output1 <- apply.method(myfun = external_function1())
output2 <- apply.method(myfun = external_function2(constant=3))
```

output 1 would be equivalent to

```
  ret.df <- my.df %>%
    mutate(z = x+y)
```

Of course, I get an error about x not being found. I know this has something to do with non-standard evaluation but cannot seem to find how to make this work. I tried a few enquo attempts but that doesn't seem to do it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up expressions and functions. One way that would work would be

```
apply.method <- function(myexpr=NULL) {
  my.df %>%
    mutate(z = !!myexpr)
}

external_function1 <- function(){
  rlang::expr(x+y)
}

external_function2 <- function(constant){
  rlang::expr(x*y + !!constant)
}

output1 <- apply.method(myexpr = external_function1())
output2 <- apply.method(myexpr = external_function2(constant=3))
```

You can learn more in the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). But when using tidyverse functions, you can create expressions or quosures and inject them into other expressions using `!!` or `!!!`

Functions in R are lexically scoped. All variables are resolved in the environment where a function is defined. Values will not be looked up in the calling environment. Lazy (non-standard) evaluation only applies to function parameters. It does not apply to function return values.

Since you want the equivant of

```
mutate(z = x+y)
```

It's important to note that `x+y` isn't a function. It's just an expression.  By default functions evaulate the expressions they contain. You must explicilty return something that is unevaulated like an `rlang::expr`, `rlang::quo` or base call object. Then you need to manually insert that unevaulated expression into your function call before evaluating that call. With `rlang` you use `!!` for that. With base R you'd need to use something like `eval()` with `bquote()` or `substitute()` or `do.call()`.

Comment: By mixing up, you mean the RHS of `z = myfun()` is an expression (for which I have inputted a function)?

Comment: Your function `external_function1` tries to add `x+y` but those aren't defined in that scope at all so when you attempt to evaluate in the function context, it can't find those variables. You need to actually create expressions if you don't want to evaluate that code. You can create expressions with `rlang::expr()` or `quote()` in base R. The when you call `myfun()`, you are evaluating that function and returning a value. The function body is not lazy-evaluated. Only the parameters passed to a function are.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I've accepted your answer. One more edge case I thought of. What if I want constant to be a variable? That is, `external_function2(constant=x)` or `external_function2(constant=y)`.

Comment: If you define a function like `external_function3 <- function(var){rlang::expr(x+{{var}})}`, then you can use `apply.method(myexpr = external_function3(y))` to get `x+y`. Just use the tools `rlang` provides to build the appropriate expression.